# Allowed referers Google API when your app is in Heroku

Tags: api, heroku, google-api, credentials

Has anyone succeed in configuring allowed referers in Google API when your app is allowed in HEROKU?

Allowed referers I tried:

```
rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/*
http://rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/
http://rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com
rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/*
*.rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/*
rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/
http://rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/*
http://rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/iniciar
rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com/iniciar
rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com
```

*.rocky-wave-5325.herokuapp.com

None of them seems to work.